# method that generate numbers unless remaining of quotient is 0 ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, symbols, division

I want to create a little method that generates 2 random numbers (num1,num2) (let's say from 1 to 100) but these numbers need to be divisable together

put in more mathematics terms, I would like to generate 2 random numbers where the remaining of the quotient is 0

I did this:

```
def operation
  operators = [:/, :+, :-, :*] 
  @operation = operators.sample
end

def result(num1, num2)
  if @operation == :/
    unless num1 % num2 != 0
      numbers
    else
      @result = @num1.send(@operation, @num2)
    end
  else
    @result = @num1.send(@operation, @num2)
  end
end

def numbers
  @num1 = rand(1..100)
  @num2 = rand(1..100)
end

numbers
result(@num1,@num2)
```

the idea is that unless the remaining of the two numbers is 0 it returns the number method again. I believe there is some iteration problem over here, as I receive an error '`result': nil is not a symbol nor a string (TypeError)'

thx

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the method `operation`, so `@operation` will be nil.  So it is invalid to use `@operation` as the method name when you call `send`.\

I suggest you refactor things so that you aren't storing a bunch of state in instance variables.  Instead, pass any data into functions using function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that there is no bias in the sampling, you must first construct the universe of all pairs that satisfy the specified conditions. You can do that as follows.

The numbers can range from `1` to a specified maximum, say

```
mx = 50
```

For this value of `mx` the list of valid pairs is constructed as follows.

```
pairs = (1..mx/2).flat_map { |n| (1..mx/n).map { |m| [n, n*m] } }
  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 2],..., [1, 50],
  #    [2, 2], [2, 4],..., [2, 50],
  #    [3, 3], [3, 6],..., [3, 48],
  #    [4, 4], [4, 8],..., [4, 48],
  #    [5, 5], [5, 10],..., [5, 50],
  #    [6, 6], [6, 12],..., [6, 48],
  #    [7, 7], [7, 14],..., [7, 49],
  #    [8, 8], [8, 16],..., [8, 48],
  #    [9, 9], [9, 18],..., [9, 45],
  #    [10, 10], [10, 20],..., [10, 50],
  #    [11, 11], [11, 22],..., [11, 44],
  #    [12, 12], [12, 24],..., [12, 48],
  #    [13, 13], [13, 26], [13, 39],
  #    [14, 14], [14, 28], [14, 42],
  #    [15, 15], [15, 30], [15, 45],
  #    [16, 16], [16, 32], [16, 48],
  #    [17, 17], [17, 34],
  #    [18, 18], [18, 36],
  #    [19, 19], [19, 38],
  #    [20, 20], [20, 40],
  #    [21, 21], [21, 42],
  #    [22, 22], [22, 44],
  #    [23, 23], [23, 46],
  #    [24, 24], [24, 48],
  #    [25, 25], [25, 50]] 

pairs_size = pairs.size
  #=> 182
```

Now you can draw random samples of, say, size

```
sample_size = 10
```

from this population, either with replacement:

```
sample_size.times.map { pairs[rand pairs_size] }
  #=> [[3, 6], [2, 10], [7, 35], [2, 40], [18, 36],
  #    [1, 45], [11, 22], [2, 40], [1, 6], [9, 36]]
```

or without replacement:

```
pairs.sample(sample_size)
  #=> [[22, 22], [6, 42], [1, 28], [1, 42], [1, 20],
  #    [1, 36], [23, 46], [9, 18], [4, 36], [16, 16]]
```

If arrays `[n, n]` (e.g, `[2, 2]`) are not to be included in `pairs`, change the block above to

```
{ |n| (2..mx/n).map { |m| [n, n*m] } }
```

in which case `pairs.size #=> 157`.